# How do I move a whole album to a directory using middle characters?

Tags: directory, mv, wildcards

im familiar with wildcards and ?, but what I want to do is move albums into their appropriate directories using the "(Disc X)" located in the middle of the file.

So, I've switched to the directory of the flashdrive in the /media/ folder (too long to list here), and i tried this, but it just put ALL the albums into the destination folder:

> mv *(Disc 3)* home/username/Music/WesRiverside3

now, mind you, the disc 3 will appear italicized when I put the asterisks around the word, if any editor wants to change it I would be happy to see how

and also all my bracket attempts have failed too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the parenthesis in the question literally in your command? If so, they are the cause of your problems. If you must have them, then escape them as `*\(disc3\)*` and it should work.
This happens because the shell is interpreting the parentheses and not using them as part of your text.